# HTTP Requests are lost when executed load test in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We are executing load tests using `JMeter` 5.1.1 tool. The test plan is created to execute for 100 threads in 60 seconds with loop 1. The `Summary Results` shows `Total` 'n' requests have been triggered however when verified in our backend/API level where only 80 requests are reached/triggered.

Where can other 20 requests gone? Is the tool really triggered for 'n' threads. Also please suggest to debug further for the lost requests.

Marked 'Delay threads until needed' in Thread Group.

Comment: check/assert requests's responses (not in summary) if any got a timeout error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of 100 requests may be successful, i.e. 20 requests may be [malformed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) or [timed out](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-00.html)

[image]
Use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect request/response details for the failing sampler(s) or look into .jtl results file, `responseCode` and `responseMessage` columns normally contain the output:

[image]

Also it worth checking [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file, in case of the error on JMeter side it should contain enough troubleshooting information.

And last but not the least, as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-released-td5728631.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, will try all the above suggestions.